# groovy convert hex to dec

Tags: java, groovy

I need to convert hex->dec using groovy, i have

```
def hex = 0x15B546EF13361F7B530C59332C60C2CE
int i= Integer.parseInt(hex,16);
```

When i run this, the error is actually showing me the value i need, but i cant get it

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt() is applicable for argument types:
>   (java.math.BigInteger, java.lang.Integer) values:
>   [**28855032353026779507009821653742961358**, ...] Possible solutions:
>   parseInt(java.lang.String, int), parseInt(java.lang.String) error at
>   line: 4

If i give the hex as string as the error suggests:

```
def hex = '0x15B546EF13361F7B530C59332C60C2CE'
```

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "0x15B546EF13361F7B530C59332C60C2CE"

What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def hex = 0x15B546EF13361F7B530C59332C60C2CE
int i = hex // int i = (hex as int)
println i
```

Groovy stores number by default in `BigDecimal`s. `0x...` notation is just different presentation of BigDecimal for compiler.

But as you can see: your hex number is very very big - so you get value that is wrong. `int` type is incapable of storing so big value: `Integer.MAX_VALUE == 2147483647` (even `long` type: `Long.MAX_VALUE == 9223372036854775807`)
You should be using standard `BigDecimal` for this or `BigInteger`.

Comment: this is working, but it returns: : **744538830**. I an expecting **28855032353026779507009821653742961358**

Comment: Thanks. BigInteger i = hex

Comment: how about if i had this hex as string? def hex = '0x15B546EF13361F7B530C59332C60C2CE' ?

Comment: @ErkiM. just trim leading 0x and use BigInteger constructor. Like this `new BigInteger(hex[2..-1], 16)`. (I have also edited Xeon's answer, providing more verbose code example, but edit is waiting for review)